# Select and Browse Categories and Subcategories Stored in Separate Tables

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, mod-rewrite, categories

I'm looking for a solution to list and browse categories and subcategories and their records (classified ads), when you store category levels in separate tables. In the past I have worked with the adjacency model but I have to stick to this database setup now, and it is new to me. I'm using php and mysql.

The site is a classified ad site structured the common way: it has the main category list on its homepage, when you click one of the category links then only its subcategories are listed and the ads that belong to this category, and so on, at every level.

I'm a bit confused in the following areas:

1. How do you construct
   the category links when browsing
   categories in order for the script to know which table it should select categories from if I consider the below
   mysql structure?  Do I need separate
   parameters at every category level I access
   like e.g: "mysite.com/?cat2=4" when
   accessing category "4" in the cat2
   table and "mysite.com/?cat3=9" when
   accessing category "9" in cat3 table
   in order to identify category
   levels? If separate parameter not
   needed, then how can php and mysql
   tell what table you have to select
   the categories from?
2. And most
   importantly in this case, what is
   the best way to construct SEO
   friendly links? And how will mysql know
   which table to select categories
   from? I would like to use the most
   simplest solution that is possible
   like:
   mysite.com/electronics/television/sony.
   As far as I know, I have to include
   at least the cat_id 
   somewhere in the link... where do I put it? and do I have to include the number of level as well? To
   complicate it more the category
   names are in foreign language with
   accented characters (though I
   created a function that changes
   accented characters into latin ones
   on the fly when generating category
   links) so I think it is best to
   select them by their ids.
3. How is a sample mysql select looks
   like that selects the child
   categories of a certain category?
4. How can I construct breadcrumb
   navigation?

**MYSQL STRUCTURE:**

- Table "cat1" (main category):

  `cat1_id | cat1_name`
- Table "cat2" (subcategory):

  `cat2_id | cat1_id | cat2_name`
- Table "cat3" (subsubcategory):

  `cat3_id | cat2_id | cat3_name`
- Table "ads":

  `ad_id | cat1_id | cat2_id | cat3_id | ad_title | ad_description`

*Thanks and sorry for the long post.*

Answer (score 1):

My favourite pattern for category (and tag) URLs:

```
http://mysite.com/articles/brains+zombies+legs+frogs
```

The `+` symbol is nice for tags, and friendly to spiders (and SEO).  Using the text of the categories is important for both spiders and humans as it's meaningful.

As for the SQL, I suggest 2 tables for anything with categories or tags:

```
Categories (id, name, description)

CategoryRelationships (catID, thingID)
```

For any given thing, you join Categories to Things via CategoryRelationships.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Things t
JOIN CategoryRelationships ON thingID = t.ID
JOIN Categories c ON catID = c.CatID
```

The result will be a list of Things and their categories, where you have only one definition of each category, and a bunch of links to the categories via the Relationship table.

As for breadcrumbs, they're a slightly different problem. Breadcrumbs either:

- Provide navigation through your site hierarchy, or
- Help the user retrace their steps

Depending on the type of breadcrumb you're aiming at, you take a different approach.  For a simple site hierarchy set of breadcrumbs, you can simply parse the URL and `foreach` over the set of segments:

```
http://mysite.com/people/zombies/brains/brains
```

Parsing the URI would result in:

```
people, zombies, brains, brains
```

For which you would generate links to each segment.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote I have to use the above mysql structure.

Comment: Was just giving an example: you can adapt to your needs. You'll just need to join once for each of your category columns.